Do I have to Disconnect Mongodb at Last on Next.js?
Sorry for poor English, it is my second language. 
I have created a function in page.js that records users' visited pages.
  async function recordSearch(character) {
    "use server";
    const db = await connectToDatabase();
    const characterSearchCollection = db.collection("CharacterSearch");
    await characterSearchCollection.insertOne({
      search_character: character,
      searched_at: new Date(),
    });
  }

After updating this code to the real server, the mongodb connection starts to being exceed.
There are about 400 users visiting per hour, which means follow 500 connections does not really make sense.
I have never used db.close() on any db related functions since it seems being disconnected automatically. What will be the solution to this case?

